# Cannot launch Packet Tracer 7

Tags: networking, cisco

Whenever I try running the Packet Tracer by entering 'packettracer' I get following output:

> Starting Packet Tracer 7.0
>   /usr/local/bin/packettracer: line 8: 13442 Aborted                 ./PacketTracer7 "$@" > /dev/null 2>&1

After each try of the installation, I got something similar. Only thing changes are the number (line 8: X).

I have followed [this guide](https://www.unixmen.com/installing-cisco-packet-tracer-linux/) to install the Packet Tracer.

Comment: Are you installing or have installed and are trying to run `packettracer` ?

Comment: @George I have already installed it and trying to run.

Answer (score 2):

I spent weeks trying to get Packet Tracer 7 to work after having the same error. I believe I have found the solution though. Should work on Ubuntu or any Debian based distribution.

Remove the package kde-style-breeze-qt4.

```
sudo apt-get remove kde-style-breeze-qt4
```

Be mindful that this may also remove programs dependent on this package. To force removal of only this package without the packages that depend on it use:

```
sudo dpkg --remove --force-depends kde-style-breeze-qt4
```

In my case the program that would have normally been removed for being dependent on kde-style-breeze-qt4 still works without it.

I hope my solution works for you. Not sure what kde-style-breeze-qt4 does but I notice that I also have kde-style-breeze on my system as well. Must be a qt library conflict or something.

Comment: How did you discover this conflicting package? I have the same error message, but `kde-style-breeze-qt4` is not installed. There is problably something else, but can't find anything in logs.

Comment: I found this by uninstalling packages related to Qt one by one until PacketTracer started to work again.

Comment: It was indeed `kde-style-breeze-qt4`. It got installed along with digikam. I removed it in accordance with your answer, yet digikam still works. Great!